# Python: Invalid Syntax error on a line that doesn't exist

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm using Notepad ++ to write my code but I keep getting an Invalid Syntax error on a line that doesn't extra.

The code stops at line 54 and it's saying the error is on line 55.

I'm assuming this is a copy and paste related error, but I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

Any suggestions would be great.

Edit - code on line 53 / 54;

city = hashmap.get(cities,'TX', 'Does Not Exist')

print "The city for the state 'TX' is: %s" % city

The error I'm getting is;

File ex38.py, line 55
                                     ^
SytanError: invalid sytanx

Comment: 1. Post your code.  2. The error is almost certainly on line 54.

Comment: Without seeing the error, or the code that produced it there's not much we can do here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to close a set of parentheses, or possibly a multiline string. Or you had a statement that takes a block (like `if x:`) on the last line and didn't follow it with anything. But most likely the parens. Somewhere there is a `(` without a corresponding `)`.

Comment: Thanks Remco, it was indeed as simple as that. I had a double parentheses that I'd only closed once.

Answer (score 0):

In the same line you are executing two instructions ,assigning and printing a variable .I think it won't work. Use newline for print statement